# Sorting Array's of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

I am working on an assignment for my C++ class (the assignment is pasted at the bottom of my test.cpp file).  I implemented everything correctly up until the last requirement (using a sort_name function, sort the student structures based on their last names and for each student, sort the classes he or she is taking based on class title.  Display the sorted list of students using the display function by calling it from main).  I have attempted to implement my sort function by sorting just the students at first, but I keep getting errors and getting stuck(The current error is: Unhandled exception at 0x777a15de in 839a4 Vasilkovskiy.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I understand that vectors are much more useful for sorting, but our professor does not want us to use them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


struct Class
{
    string title; 
    int units;
    char grade;

};
struct Student
{
    string name;
    double gpa;
    Class classes[500];
};

int const SIZE = 50;
void initStudent(Student[], int);
void readStudent(Student[], int,  int&);
void gpaCalculate(Student&);
void print(Student[], int);
void sort_name(Student[], int);
void swapStus(Student&, Student&);
void stringToCharArray(string, char[]);
int locactionOfFirstName(Student[], int, int);

int main()
{   
    int numberOfStudents = 0;
    Student students[SIZE];
    initStudent(students, SIZE);
    readStudent(students, SIZE, numberOfStudents);

    for(int i = 0; students[i].name != "";i++)
        gpaCalculate(students[i]);
    print(students, numberOfStudents);
    sort_name(students, numberOfStudents);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void initStudent(Student st[], int s)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        st[i].gpa = 0.0;
    }

}

void readStudent(Student st[], int s, int& nStus)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {   
        string tmpName;

        cout << "Enter student name: ";
        getline(cin, tmpName);
        if(tmpName == "")
            break;
        st[i].name = tmpName;
        nStus++;


        for(int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        {   
            string tmpTitle;
            cout << "Enter class title: ";
            getline(cin, tmpTitle);
            if (tmpTitle == "")
                break;
            st[i].classes[j].title = tmpTitle;

            cout << "Enter units for " << st[i].classes[j].title << ": " ;
            cin >> st[i].classes[j].units;
            cout << "Enter grade for " << st[i].classes[j].title << ": " ;
            cin >> st[i].classes[j].grade;
            cin.ignore();
        }   
    }
}


void gpaCalculate (Student& s)
{
    double unitsByPoints = 0;
    double totalUnits = 0;

    for (int i = 0; s.classes[i].title != ""; i++)
    {

        int grade = 0;
        char ltrGrade = s.classes[i].grade;
        switch (ltrGrade)
        {
        case 'A':
            grade = 4;
                break;
        case 'B':
            grade = 3;
                break;
        case 'C':
            grade = 2;
                break;
        case 'D':
            grade = 1;
                break;
        case 'F':
            grade = 0;
                break;
        }
        unitsByPoints += s.classes[i].units*grade;
        totalUnits += s.classes[i].units;

    }
    s.gpa = unitsByPoints/totalUnits;
}

void print(Student st[], int size)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Student's name: " <<  st[i].name << endl;
        for (int j = 0; st[i].classes[j].title != ""; j++)
        {
            cout << st[i].classes[j].title << "," << st[i].classes[j].grade << endl;
        }
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << "GPA: " <<  st[i].gpa << endl;
    }
}

//void sort_name(Student st[], int size)
//{ 
//  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
//  {
//      int smallest = locactionOfFirstName(st, i, size);
//      swapStus(st[i], st[smallest]);
//  }
//
//}

void swapStus(Student& s1, Student& s2)
{
    Student tempStu;
    tempStu = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = tempStu;
}

void stringToCharArray(string s, char c[])
{
    char tempCharArray[50];
    for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\n'; i++)
    {
        tempCharArray[i] = s[i];
    }
    char * space = strstr(tempCharArray," ");
    strcpy(c,space);
}

bool lastNameCompare(string l1, string l2)
{
    char lName1[50];
    char lName2[50];
    stringToCharArray(l1, lName1);
    stringToCharArray(l2, lName2);
    return (strcmp(lName1, lName2) >=0);
}

int locactionOfFirstName(Student st[],int start, int size)
{
    char lName1[50];
    char lName2[50];
    stringToCharArray(st[0].name, lName1);
    int i;
    for(i = start; i < size;)
    {
        stringToCharArray(st[i].name, lName2);
        if(strcmp(lName1, lName2) >= 0 )
        {
            stringToCharArray(st[i].name, lName1);
        }
    }
    return i;
}

void InsertItem(Student values[], int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
  bool finished = false;
  int current = endIndex;
  bool moreToSearch = (current != startIndex);

  while (moreToSearch && !finished)
  {
    if (lastNameCompare(values[current-1].name, values[current].name))
    {
      swapStus(values[current], values[current-1]);
      current--;
      moreToSearch = (current != startIndex);
    }
    else
      finished = true;
  }
}

void sort_name(Student values[], int numValues)
{
  for (int count = 0; count < numValues; count++)
    InsertItem(values, 0, count);
}
/*



Define a structure called Class (with uppercase C) with the following data:
title, units and grade.

Define a structure called Student with the following data:
name (full name), gpa, and classes which is an array of Class structures (all the classes the student has taken so far).

Write an initialize function that receives an array of Student structures and its size and sets the gpa of all to 0.0.

In main, create 50 Students and call the above function to initialize the gpa for all 50 Students to 0.0. 

Then, pass the array of student structures and its size to a read function that will read student data from the user and store the entered data in the array of student structures.  The user will enter student name followed by the class title, units and grade received for each class he or she has taken.  When finished entering class information for a student, the user will just press Enter (an empty string) and to end entering more students, he or she will do the same for the student name. 

Example:

Enter student name: Maria Gomez

Enter class title: English 101
Enter units for English 101: 3 
Enter grade for English 101: A

Enter class title: Math 201
Enter units for Math 201: 4
Enter grade for Math 201: B

Enter class title: [User enters RETURN to indicate no more classes]

Enter student name: Kevin Duran

Enter class title: Poly Sci 101
Enter units for Poly Sci 101: 3 
Enter grade for Poly Sci 101: A

Enter class title: Math 201
Enter units for Math 201: 4
Enter grade for Math 201: B

Enter class title: [User enters RETURN to indicate no more classes]

Enter student name: [User enters RETURN to indicate no more students]

Once all Studnets have been entered, pass each element of the array of Student structures (element by element) to a gpa function which will compute and return the gpa for each Student using the classes array within each Student structure which contains the units and grade for each class taken by the student.  Store the gpa returned by the above function in the gpa member of the Student structures.  GPA is calculated by multiplying the number of units for each class by the points received for that class, and then adding all these products together and dividing it by total number of units.  The points received for a class is based on the grade: for A, it's 4; for B, it's 3; for C, it's 2; for D it's 1; and for F it's 0.  For example, if a student has take 3 classes with 3, 4, and 3 units and has received A, B, and C for these classes, respectively, then, the GPA will be 3 x 4 + 4 x 3 + 3 x 2 / 10 = 3.0.

Print all students showing name, followed by all classes taken, the grade received and the gpa using a display function which receives the array and its size as parameters.

Then, using a sort_name function, sort the student structures based on their last names and for each student, sort the classes he or she is taking based on class title.  Display the sorted list of students using the display function by calling it from main.

For example:

Kevn Duran
Poly Sci 101, A
Math 150, B
GPA: 3.0

Maria Gomez:
English 101, A
Math 201, C
GPA: 2.9

Robert Small
Comp Science 801, C
Comp Science 802, D
GPA: 1.9

Tom Wang
Comp Science 808, A
Comp Science 839, B
GPA: 3.5

Then, sort the students based on their GPA's using a sort_gpa function and print the list again using the display function. 

Then, ask what to search for - name or gpa.  If name is selected, read a student name from the user and, using a binary search function that takes the array, its size and the name to search for, finds the student and displays all of his or her information (name, gpa, units and list of classes taken).

Example:

Enter a student name:  Robert Small

Robert Small:
Comp Science 801, C
Comp Science 802, B
GPA: 2.5

If GPA is selected, read a GPA and using another binary search find the student with the given GPA by passing the students array, its size and the GPA to search for.  Display the name of the student with the specified GPA in main.  

Example:

Enter GPA to search for:  2.5

Robert Small was found with the GPA of 2.5

If the name or GPA is not found, tell the user it was not found; e.g.: There was no student with a GPA of 2.5; or Robert Small was not found.

Then, pass the array of student atructures and the size to a stats function which will return the average of the GPA's of all students and through two reference parameters will output the student structures that have the minimum and maximum GPA's.  Print the average GPA, as well as the names of the students who have the minimum and maximum GPA in main, like so:

Average GPA = 3.17

Robert Small has the minimum GPA of 2.5.

Tom Wang has the maximum GPA of 3.5. 

Finally, read a maximum and minimum GPA from the user and pass the array of student structures and its size, as well as two other arrays of student structures of the same size to a function which will store all students with a GPA of above the minimum in the highGPA array and all those with a GPA below the maximum in the lowGPA array.  Display the students stored in these two arrays by passing them each from main to the display function.  In other words, the highlow function receives two uninitalized arrays of student structures and populates them based on the GPA criteria passed to it (minimum GPA and maximum GPA).  Then, upon return to main, main passes each of these arrays to the display function to display them.  For example, if the user enters 2.0 for the maximum GPA, the lowGPA array gets filled out with all those students who have a GPA of less than 2.0.  Likewise, if the minimum GPA is 3.5, the highlow function populates the highGPA array with those students who have a GPA of 3.5 or higher.

Example:

Enter maximum GPA:  2.0

Enter minimum GPA:  3.5

Students with a GPA of lower than 2.0:

Robert Small 1.9

Students with a GPA of 3.5 or higher:

Tom Wang 3.5

When writing the highlow function, take advantage of the fact that the array elements are sorted based on the GPA, so to find all the students with a GPA of equal to or higher than the minimum GPA, it doesn't make sense to start from the first element in the array. Instead you can start from the midpoint. If the midpoint is lower than the minimum GPA, you can increment the index until the midpoint is no longer smaller and then all the GPA's from that point on will be larger and part of the high GPA's.  For low GPA's of course, you'd want to start from the beginning of the array and compare and store each that's lower than the maximum until they are no longer lower.

Functions you must write for this assignment (in addition to main):

initialize, read, display, sort_name, sort_gpa, search-name, search_gpa, stats, highlow.

Upload your cpp and exe files using the Browse and Upload buttons below and click Finish once both have been uploaded to the site.*/
```

Comment: So on what line do you get the error? Tried debugging?

Comment: Its very frustrating when people vote down your question without explaining why.  If you are going to vote something down, at least give some constructive criticism.

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote button is "this question doesn't show any research effort". And I agree. You didn't narrow it down, you didn't say where the error occurs, plus it's unlikely that this question will help anyone else in the future. There's your explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I believe the error happens when sort_name(students, numberOfStudents) is called in main, but I am not sure.  I am very new to programming and finding run time errors in debug mode is very challenging for me.

Comment: "I believe the error happens" is not good enough. Debugging skills should, IMO, be learned before debugging. It's like learning how to write the numbers before you do math. So, if you don't know how to debug yet, learn. I can't stress how important this is.

Comment: There are two reasons for 'stack overflow' error: 1) Infinite recursion 2) Too many/too large locally declared objects. I don't see any recursive calls in your code... If you haven't read about local vs dynamic allocation, it's time to do so.

Comment: "NOTE: I understand that vectors are much more useful for sorting, but our professor does not want us to use them." Really? How does he feel about **`std::sort`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I debugged it for you.

The problem is in your `stringToCharArray(string s, char c[])`.

My index `i` arrived to `104` before getting "segmentation fault". Since all your strings have length `50` you are clearly going out of bounds.

Another problem is in `srtstr` that returns `NULL`, but this is related to the first problem.

A quick look to your `sort_name` and `InsertItem` didn't show up anything wrong, at least in the field of "segmentation error", since it's not so clear what you are trying to do, but at least you are performing the right index checks.

Comment: btw, you may want to learn how to debug, or you will never be able to face this problems.