# Sorting an array of structures

Tags: c++

I'm studying c++ and I was given the task. I need to created structure `Student`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

const int num = 5;

struct Student  {
    string name;
    int groupNumber;
    int progress[num];
};
```

and work with it.
it's my programm

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

int n;
cout << "Input n = ";
cin >> n;
cin.ignore();

Student * Group = new Student[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    cout << "Input name: ";
    getline (cin, Group[i].name);
    Group[i].groupNumber = rand()%5 + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        Group[i].progress[j] = rand()%5 + 2;
    }
}

int * groupNumberArray = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    groupNumberArray[i] = Group[i].groupNumber;
}

for (int i; i < n - 1; ++i)
{
    int min = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (groupNumberArray[min] <= groupNumberArray[j]) continue;
        min = j;
    }
    if (min != i)
    {
        int temp = groupNumberArray[i];
        groupNumberArray[i] = groupNumberArray[min];
        groupNumberArray[min] = temp;

        Student * tempStudent = &Group[i];
        &Group[min] = &Group[i];
        &Group[i] = tempStudent;
    }
}

cout << "\n\n";

delete [] Group;
delete [] groupNumberArray;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

I need to sort students in accordance with the growth of groupNumber.
I tried to use pointers but it works wrong. How to make the sorting works the right way?

Comment: Please state your requirements, otherwise we'll just say "use `std::sort` with a suitable predicate, the end".

Comment: The C++ way would be: Provide a comparator for the Student struct and just use the sort algorithm.

Comment: Declare `group` as `std::vector<Student> group;` then use `std::sort` ....

Comment: Great prediction juanchopanza :)

Comment: I'm just starting to learn С++, I dont know about `std::sort` and about `std::vector`. I need to use simple ways.

Comment: In C++ the "simple" ways *are* to use `std::sort`.  They also happen to be the *correct* ways.  I guess this is more a condemnation of whomever is teaching you C++.

Comment: Yes, I understand I need to learn `std::sort` and other complicated things and I'm going to start soon, but maybe there is a way I can use now? With pointers, maybe.

Comment: @dornhege `The C++ way would be: Provide a comparator for the Student struct and just use the sort algorithm. ` Can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: Look up the documentation for sort, ask if you get stuck once you've tried something.

Comment: Please stop adding the tags to the title of your questions. Also, didn’t you ask this *exact* question a few days ago?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph No, I asked about creating structure

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting Array's of Structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185809/sorting-arrays-of-structs)

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is to use `std::sort` with a comparator method on your array.

Example:

```
bool Compare_By_Group(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
  return a.groupNumber /* insert comparison operator here */ b.groupNumber;
}

// The sort function call
    std::sort(&Group[0],
              &Group[/* last index + 1*/],
              Compare_By_Group);
```

Comment: `&Group[/* last index + 1*/]` is illegal C++ (UB). Use `Group + N` instead (there’s really no reason to use `&Group[0]` instead of pointer decay of `Group`, except for reasons of overload resolution).

Answer (score 1):

```
    vector<Student> students(n);
    .. populate students
    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), [](const Student& left, const Student& right){ return left.groupNumber < right.groupNumber; });
```